# Powershell how to add data in the csv file to one column

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file with a few columns. For example

```
col1;col2;col3;col4  
text1;text2;text3;text4  
text5;text6;text7;text8  
text9;text10;text11;text12
```

I want to add text to column `col3`, like this:

```
col1;col2;col3;col4  
text1;text2;append\text3;text4  
text5;text6;append\text7;text8  
text9;text10;append\text11;text12
```

So question is:
**How to do this?**

(*I'm stuck whit that how I add data to each column in `col3`.*)

Answer (score 3):

You probably know how to read/write data. To change the data, send them to `Foreach-Object`, alter the data and pass the object further to `Export-Csv`.

```
Import-Csv d:\temp\so\csv1.txt  -Delimiter ';' | 
   ForEach-Object { $_.col3 = 'append\' +$_.col3; $_ } | 
   Export-Csv d:\temp\so\csv2.txt -Delimiter ';'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have even tried this code before but there seems to be that I have few code format errors...Need to study more. Problem solved!

Comment: No problem :) I see that we both with Keith added the same answer. Funny ;)

Answer (score 3):

Give this a whirl:

```
Import-Csv -Delim ';' cols.csv | 
    ForEach-Object {$_.col3 = "prepend\$($_.col3)";$_} |
    Export-Csv cols2.csv -Delim ';' -NoTypeInformation
```

Use the `-NoTypeInformation` parameter to avoid this comment getting put at the top of your CSV:

```
#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
```

However, if you don't mind the comment then you can leave off the `-NoTypeInformation` parameter.

Comment: The `-NoTypeInformation` is now default behavior.